# Convert DWG/shp format for Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I need to convert DWG/shp files to some vector data file that is supported in 
Openlayers (e.g KML,GML). I tried following [this guide](http://acadconverter.chrismichaelis.com/v2012/#) but it doesn't work.

Please advise me some converter (not necessarily free) that I can use.

Comment: FME is good  (basic version costs 1000€+ i think )

Comment: An alternative solution is to combine Openlayers and Mapserver.

Comment: found very nice converter online: http://geoconverter.hsr.ch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shapefile - simply open shp in QGIS and on the Layer menu -> "Save as", it can save to KML, GML, GeoJSON and many more.

For DWG it is a bit harder because it is not open format, you will need some comercial tool to convert it to DXF 2000/2000i/2002 version. Then DXF file you can also open in QGIS (it uses GDAL/OGR behind the scene).

For converting DWG to DXF 2000/2000i/2002 you can use e.g. Microstation, Teigha libraries, AutoCAD.. If you need the converting automatically done on server side  at runtime then it's more complicated, two possible solutions:

http://geokods.com/#!/blog/view/v8_dgn_dwg_gdal_ogr_dxf_patches

Comment: I tried to convert shapefile to KML with QGIS it goes well, but when i tried to convert DXF with QGIS its not supported. any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps your DXF file is not in version 2000/2000i/2002. QGIS uses "ogr" to open DXF files, you can test from console whether ogr can read your DXF file, with command like:
ogrinfo.exe path_to_your_dxf_file.dxf

Answer (score -1):

You could try using QGIS or FWtools is a nice user friendly package og GDAL/ ORG tools set. Have a look at ogr2ogr.exe and maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409974/converting-a-cad-file-to-a-shape-file) will be of help

Comment: an easy way og installing (on windows) some really good open source GIS software is via OSGEO installers https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: Adiitionally, FWtools is outdated, and may not include latest drivers and coordinate sytsem definitions. http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/ has the most recent version of GDAL.